# python list in Recursion

Tags: python

I want to find all links in a div, for example:

```
<div>
  <a href="#0"></a>
  <a href="#1"></a>
  <a href="#2"></a>
</div>
```

So I write a func as follow:

```
def get_links(div):
    links = []
    if div.tag == 'a':
        links.append(div)
        return links   
    else:
        for a in div:
            links + get_links(a)
        return links
```

*why the results is **[]** rather than **[a, a, a]**?*  ------- question

I know this is a question of list reference, could you show some detail

This is the complete module:

```
import lxml.html


def get_links(div):
    links = []
    if div.tag == 'a':
        links.append(div)
        return links   
    else:
        for a in div:
            links + get_links(a)
        return links


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fragment = '''
        <div>
          <a href="#0">1</a>
          <a href="#1">2</a>
          <a href="#2">3</a>
        </div>'''
    fragment = lxml.html.fromstring(fragment)
    links = get_links(fragment)    # <---------------
```

Comment: Try changing `links + get_links(a)` to `links += get_links(a)`

Comment: If you don't change `links`, who else should do it?

Comment: Yes, This is the right way. Thanks. I want to write +=, but I forget, and I think I write is +=. so I dont find the error... and I think this is a question of list reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List addition in Python returns a new list obtained from the concatenation of the arugments, doesn't change them:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(x + [5, 6])  # displays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(x)           # here x is still [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you can use the `extend` method:

```
x.extend([5, 6])
```

or also `+=`

```
x += [5, 6]
```

The latter is IMO a bit "strange" because it's a case in which `x=x+y` is not the same as `x+=y` and therefore I prefer to avoid it and make the in-place extension more explicit.

For your code

```
links = links + get_links(a)
```

would also be acceptable but remember that it does a different thing: it allocates a new list with the concatenation and then assign the name `links` to point to it: it doesn't change the original object referenced by `links`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x
x = x + [5, 6]
print(x)   # displays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(y)   # displays [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = x
x += [5, 6]
print(x)   # displays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(y)   # displays [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Yes, This is the right way.Thank you! I want to write +=, but I forget, and I think I write is +=. so I dont find the error... and I think this is a question of list reference

Answer (score 1):

If tag is not 'a' your code looks like that.

```
# You create an empty list

links = []
for a in div:
    # You combine <links> with result of get_links() but you do not assign it to anything
    links + get_links(a)
# So you return an empty list   
return links
```

You should change `+` with `+=`:

```
links += get_links(a)
```

Or use `extend()`

```
links.extend(get_links(a))
```

Comment: Yes, This is the right way. I want to write +=, but I forget, and I think I write is +=. so I dont find the error... and I think this is a question of list reference

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use `xpath` method to get all `a` tags from `div` at any level.

Code:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(content)
print root.xpath('//div//a')
```

Output:

```
[<Element a at 0xb6cef0cc>, <Element a at 0xb6cef0f4>, <Element a at 0xb6cef11c>]
```

Comment: Your code only returns `a` tags that are direct children to the `div` tag. `'//div//a'` is better.

Comment: @infgeoax: yes agree. Updated code to get `a` tags from `div` at any level. Thanx.